# pip install modules to 2.7.10 rather than 2.7.13 causing default python2.7.13 can't import those modules on MAC terminal window

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pymysql

As u can see from the question, I run `sudo pip install pymysql` successfully.

But it seems to be installed in 2.7.10 rather 2.7.13. I find it when tried to get python version before as well as after using `sudo -i`.
[image]
[image]
 Then I listed all modules install using `help('modules')` and suprisingly to find 2.7.10 has but 2.7.13 don't have pymsql .

It failed to run `pip2.7.13 install pymysql` .Only `pip2.7 install pymysql` works .

**I wonder how to config pip to install modules to 2.7.x or change my default python version from 2.7.13 to 2.7.10 ?**

Comment: Why are you trying to use sudo? That uses the system Python, version 2.7.10

Answer (score 0):

You may try to install python packages without root permission:

```bash
pip install --user pymysql
```

The option `--user`  allow pip to install packages in your `\home` directory instead. That means it doesn't need any special privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the cause：

My computer has an software named MAMP which has python2.7.13 env itself and pushes the python to the global.But pip will install modules into the computer's own python2.7.10, which causes now global python2.7.13 cannot import the installed modules. 
Solution：
1，Find out the location of modules installed by pip and copy them to the
 python directory in mamp. Commands as below:

cp -r /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymysql/* /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/python2.7/pymysql/

2， Then I can feely import modules installed by pip in global python now ~